# Numerical solution to heat equation

Tags: c, differential-equations

After solving the heat equation with analytical procedures, I'm trying to solve it numerically by the explicit Euler method. I'm given the [following discretization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpoXF.png), where T is the temperature. My code is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 100

double T[N+1][N];

int main(){
    int i,j;
    double dt=1./N;
    double dz=1./N;
    double b=43351./94400;
    for (i=0;i<N+2;i++){
        T[i][0]=b;
        T[i][N-1]=b;
    }
    
    for (j=0;j<N+1;j++){
        T[0][j+1]=b;
    }
    for (i=0;i<N+1;i++){
        for (j=1;j<N;j++){
            T[i+1][j] = (dt/pow(dz, 2))*(T[i][j+1] - 2*T[i][j] + T[i][j-1]) + dt + T[i][j];
            
        }
    }

    FILE* output;
    
    output = fopen("numerica.txt", "w");
    
    for (i=0;i<N+2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<N+1;j++){
            fprintf(output, "%lf\t", T[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(output,"\n");
    }
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
        
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a N+1xN matrix that saves all the values from the function. After compiling it I have an infinite .txt file. Some help?

Comment: It should have 102 lines with 101 numbers on each line. There is no way this produces an infinite file. A typo in a `for` loop can easily make it infinite by mistake, but you didn't make a typo.

Comment: Can you specify *infinite* ? Does the program never stop running?

Comment: Don't bother with the `fopen`.  Just redirect in the shell with`> numerica.txt`.  If you do use `fopen`, you need to use it properly and check that it  succeeds.

Comment: The 2nd for loop is clearly wrong.  On the final iteration, j == N and `T[0][j+1]=b;` is assigning outside the bounds of T, so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: I corrected the 2nd for, but still getting error.

Comment: You should figure out if the problem is in the writing of the file or not, and then remove the code that is not necessary

Comment: Note that this line `T[i+1][j] = (dt/pow(dz, 2))*(T[i][j+1] - 2*T[i][j] + T[i][j-1]) + dt + T[i][j];` doesn't make any sense. You are adding the second derivative ∂²T/∂z² times dt to dt and to a temperature, to create a new temperature. `T[i][j]` term is consistent. So is the first term, since dt×∂²T/∂z² is (that is what heat equation says) dt×C×∂T/∂t, so this is also a temperature (a temperature difference). But term `dt` is inconsistent. You cannot add kelvin and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The output file should have 102 lines unless the program crashes, as your loops are wrong.

```
$ gcc -O -Wall t.c 
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:35:13: warning: iteration 100 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   35 |             fprintf(output, "%lf\t", T[i][j]);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.c:34:19: note: within this loop
   34 |         for (j=0;j<N+1;j++){
      |                  ~^~~~
t.c:24:46: warning: iteration 98 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   24 |             T[i+1][j] = (dt/pow(dz, 2))*(T[i][j+1] - 2*T[i][j] + T[i][j-1]) + dt + T[i][j];
      |                                          ~~~~^~~~~
t.c:23:19: note: within this loop
   23 |         for (j=1;j<N;j++){
      |                   ^
t.c:20:18: warning: iteration 99 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   20 |         T[0][j+1]=b;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~
t.c:19:15: note: within this loop
   19 |     for (j=0;j<N+1;j++){
      |              ~^~~~
t.c:15:16: warning: iteration 101 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   15 |         T[i][0]=b;
      |         ~~~~~~~^~
t.c:14:15: note: within this loop
   14 |     for (i=0;i<N+2;i++){
      |              ~^~~~
```

Comment: oh, that is good spotting. The compiler is allowed to turn a loop like this into an infinite one!

Answer (score 0):

As vm666 pointed out, the compiler notices that the loop reads past the end of the array `T`, which is *undefined behaviour*. The compiler is allowed to do anything with undefined behaviour. In this case - where a certain iteration of the loop - the compiler might have assumed that iteration 101 never happens. This is an allowed interpretation of undefined behaviour, because it's (surprisingly) often correct. Then, the compiler can reason that if iteration 101 never happens, some magical force (like calling `exit`) must stop the loop before iteration 101, so it can never get past iteration 101, so it never needs to check whether it gets past iteration 101, and the program can be a bit faster if it never actually checks and the loop is just infinite.

Sneaky compiler.

If this is actually the reason, you can fix it by not printing numbers from outside the array. It seems you accidentally added another +1 to both the `i` and `j` loops so just take that off again.